# Why does netty example for HttpStaticFileServer use RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, http, netty

Is there any specific reason for netty [HttpStaticFileServerHandler](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.html) example to use RandomAccessFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it so that they can demonstrate the use of `ChunkedFile`, which requires a `RandomAccessFile`.  And the reason for that seems to be that `ChunkedFile` needs to be able to get the file's length.

---

> If I am not using https, I need not use `ChunkedFile`. So I can choose `FileInputStream` instead of `RandomAccessFile` which also returns a `FileChannel`. But I cannot get fileLength from `FileInputStream` which is a required input for `DefaultFileRegion`. So I think it is necessary to use `RandomAccessFile`.

That's roughly correct.  However, you could potentially get the file length some other way; e.g. using `File.length()`.

Actually, it doesn't make much difference which way you get the `FileChannel` and the file length.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! If I am not using https, I need not use ChunkedFile. So I can choose FileInputStream instead of RandomAccessFile which also returns a FileChannel. But I cannot get fileLength from FileInputStream which is a required input for DefaultFileRegion. So I think it is necessary to use RandomAccessFile. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

A RAF is required to support zero-copy which requires a FileChannel which is most commonly acquired from a RAF.